# jQuery - Replace div class when click a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, replace

Can someone help me write a jQuery script to replace a div class to another class when a link is clicked.
I have a list of addresses, and I want a map image to change when an address is clicked. Due to the structure of the css and gradients on the image, simply changing the backround-image url won't help.
I am creating 4 classes for each of the addresses, each with the background image that image of each address.

I have simplified my code so that it is easier to write a script. This is what I have built:

The image wrapper:

```
<div class="map-wrapper map1">
</div>
```

The address list:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#map1">Address 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#map2">Address 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#map3">Address 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#map4">Address 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

The jQuery I had before, when I simply changed an  within the map-grad tags.

```
 var itemInfo = { // Initialise the item information
      img1: ['/img/map.png', ''],
      img2: ['/img/ealing_map.jpg', ''],
};

$(function() {
      $('#maps a').click(function() { // When an item is selected
            var id = $(this).attr('href').replace(/#/, ''); // Retrieve its ID
            $('#info img').attr('src', itemInfo[id][0]); // Set the image
            $('#info p').text(itemInfo[id][1]); // And text
            return false; // Prevent default behaviour
      });
});
```

I want to write a jQuery script that changes the class 'map1' to 'map2, 3 or 4' when the relevant address link is clicked. This in turn will change the background image! :)

So, can anyone please help me! I am a javascript and jQuery newbie and know not an awful lot!

Comment: What is `#maps`? The `<ul>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('ul li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cl = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
    $('.map-wrapper').removeClass().addClass('map-wrapper '+cl);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kLm3H/)

Comment: @LightStyle - just noticed it myself, typing to fast I guess, thanks!

Comment: It can happen sometimes, don't worry :D +1!

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
$('.map-wrapper').removeClass().addClass('map-wrapper '+$(this).attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following add the end of your function:

```
$(".map-wrapper").removeClass("map1 map2 map3 map4").addClass(id);
```